# Rails 2.3.2 + mysql2 + MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Is it possible with problems set up Rails 2.3.2 APP with mysql2 RubyGem and MySQL 5.5 without compobility problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that any 0.2.x version of mysql2 should be compatible with 2.3.x rails versions.